# Testing if a checkbox is checked chnage li items class

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I added li items for append method, I want to change li item class if checkbox checked.

that's the append code

```
 $('#submit').on('click', function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var invitee = $('#inviteName').val();
       console.log(invitee); $('#invitedList').append('<li>'+invitee+'<br>'+'<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="confirm" id="confirm">'+"Confirmed"+'<br>'+'<button type="submit" name="edit" value="edit" id="edit">edit</button>'+'<button type="submit" name="remove" value="remove" id="remove">remove</button>'+'</li>');
});
```

that's change class code

```
$('#invitedList').on('change','#confirm',function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault;
   var isChecked = false;
  if (document.getElementById('confirm').checked) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('responded');
  } else {
   $(this).parent().addClass('');
  }
});
```

HTML code

```
<form id="registrar">
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Invite Someone" id="inviteName">
   <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</header>

<div class="main">  
  <h2>Invitees</h2>
  <ul id="invitedList"></ul>    
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share the relevant HTML

Comment: you code worked fine for me.Pls add html in your question not in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem with multiple element click.try with `class="confirm"` instead of `id` .And do with `removeClass` for else statement

```js
$('#submit').on('click', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var invitee = $('#inviteName').val();
    console.log(invitee);
    $('#invitedList').append('<li>'+invitee+'<br>'+'<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="confirm" class="confirm">'+"Confirmed"+'<br>'+'<button type="submit" name="edit" value="edit" id="edit">edit</button>'+'<button type="submit" name="remove" value="remove" id="remove">remove</button>'+'</li>');
});

$('#invitedList').on('change','.confirm',function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault;
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('responded');
    } else {
      $(this).parent().removeClass('responded');
    }
});
```

```css
.responded{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="registrar"> <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Invite Someone" id="inviteName"> <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit">Submit</button> </form> </header> <div class="main"> <h2>Invitees</h2> <ul id="invitedList"></ul> </div> </div>
```